# template copy of derived class

Tags: c++, polymorphism, template-classes

I'm making copy of template class that can contain pointer on object or pointer of derived class. I tried with allocation on heap but it continuously making object of main class, doesn't matter is it of derived or main class. How can I fix it. Code is huge, this is a part where I tried it:

```cpp
template<typename T> 
inline void Pair<T>::copy(const Pair& p) {
    pointerAttribute1 = new T(*p.getFirst());//this is an object of main class in my main
    pointerAttribute2 = new T(*p.getSecond());//this is an object of derived class in my main
}
```

Comment: Please show how you use this method.  It going to make a new `T`s so it all depends on how you call it.

Comment: You're looking for what's sometimes called [a virtual constructor](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/virtual-functions#virtual-ctors) or a clone.

Comment: I'm making a few assumptions here, but it looks like OP is using runtime polymorphism, creating objects of type Base and Derived and using pairs of type Pair<Base*, Base*>; that would explain `new T` would always create objects of type `Base*`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your pair has two types.

So why not represent that in the template?
Something [like](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5049713aa6554dc):

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> 
inline void Pair<T1, T2>::copy(const Pair<T1, T2>& p) {
    if(this == &p) return;
    delete p1;
    delete p2;
    p1 = new T1(*p.p1);
    p2 = new T2(*p.p2);
}
```

But then, maybe instead of implementing copy you can go [with assignment operator](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97ad25bd9efcb46b):

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> 
inline Pair<T1, T2>& Pair<T1, T2>::operator=(const Pair<T1, T2>& p) {
    if(this != &p) {
        delete p1;
        delete p2;
        p1 = new T1(*p.p1);
        p2 = new T2(*p.p2);
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it has, but I wanted to pass only pointer of main class, and I wondered can I somehow know is pointing on object of main or derived class, and depending on that to make an object. I wanted to use polymorphism.